# No WEBCAM drivers found under imaging devices after upgrading to Windows 10 from 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, webcam

My grandfather asked me to update his windows 7 laptop (ASUS Eee PC Seashell Series) to windows 10 and after I upgraded it to Windows 10 the webcam is not working and neither I was able to find any driver for it there aren't any driver under imaging devices and I also went to the driver utility page of ASUS and I couldn't find a driver so I don't know what to do!

I have tried hardware troubleshooting and windows doesn't seeems to find any issue!

The webcam is important for his Skype Video sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support by ASUS for this laptop on Windows 10. Microsoft evidently does not recognize the device.

You may try to find in the Device Manager the camera manufacturer and then
try to find a driver on his Support website, but I'm not too hopeful.

Otherwise I advise to revert to Windows 7.
Going back is only possible during the first 28 days after the
upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: I have erased the old windows installation!

Comment: So now if I buy my Grandpa an external USB WebCam and install the driver via legacy driver tool will it work?

Comment: No reason to erase an old windows installation - it's emptied almost totally by Windows after 28 days. Buy a webcam that comes with a driver or is labelled as Windows 10 generic, but with a clear return policy.